# Default to numbers view on textfield focus

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, titanium-mobile

I am trying to make a `UITextField` default to the numbers view of the keyboard on focus, the same as e.g. the "Zip" field in the iPhones contacts/addressbook app. I know the KEYBOARD_* constants of the Ti.UI module, none of those seem to do the trick though, as I do not want to disallow alpha characters

- I just want the numbers to be auto focused.

The field will be to describe a value, which in most cases will be a monetary value, and therefore a number, but in some cases it may be something like "2 pieces".

I am working with Titanium SDK 2, iOS 5.1, iOS Simulator on OS X 10.7.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why would you edit my question to make a list item out of something that is not part of a list Jacky Boy?

Answer (score 0):

here it is

```
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
```

read here more about it

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType

Comment: That's actually just numbers.

Comment: Yes, as described in the question: "as I do not want to disallow alpha characters I just want the numbers to be auto focused".

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the Keyboard `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`. The reason it wasn't working was that I wrote `keyBoardType` instead of `keyboardType`. My bad.